# How can i retrieve context from for loop in views django and send it to template

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need to do one page with topic and all entries about this topic. And for each entries I need all comments shown up below each entry. Comments should be for exact entry. Cant find it solution and decided ask. Thank you.

**models.py**

```
 --snip--
    class Comment(models.Model):
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        text = models.TextField()
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```

**views.py**

```
--snip--
    def topic(request, topic_id):
        topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
        entries = topic.entry_set.all()
        comments = []
        for entry in entries:
            c = entry.comment_set.all()
            comments.append(c)
        context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries,
                   'comments': comments}
        return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html'
                      ,context)
```

**topic.html**

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>{{ topic.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ topic.description }}</p><br>
    <p>Entries:</p><br>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.text }}</li>
            <ul>
                <p>Comments:</p>
                {% for comment in comments %}
                    <li>{{ comment.text }}</li>
                {% endfor %}<br>
            </ul>
        {% empty %}
            <li>Not entries</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: tip : you can add the python tag and also add a lnguage identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just `topic`. No need to get `entries` and `comments`:

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>{{ topic.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ topic.description }}</p><br>
    <p>Entries:</p><br>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in topic.entry_set.all %}
            <li>{{ entry.text }}</li>
            <ul>
                <p>Comments:</p>
                {% for comment in entry.comment_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ comment.text }}</li>
                {% endfor %}<br>
            </ul>
        {% empty %}
            <li>Not entries</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

You will also want to optimise the query using `prefetch_related` so you don't hit the db per entry per comment:

```
topic = Topic.objects.prefetch_related('entry_set__comment_set').get(id=topic_id))
context = {'topic': topic}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```